# clang - Verify embeding of bitcode

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, archive

I'm currently compiling the [libint library](https://github.com/evaleev/libint/wiki#compiling-libint-library). [This](https://github.com/evaleev/libint/releases/download/v2.7.0-beta.3/libint-2.7.0-beta.3.tgz) release to be specific. During the process, an libint2.a archive is created.
I'd like to add the right compile flags such that the llvm-bc will be embeded into the object file and as a consequence into that archive.

For the first part, I've read that instead of using the fembed-bitcode flag, most people
prefer using -flto, as lto will already imply the embedding.
So the following Flags should be fine, right? lld links to an appropriate llvm-lld.
`-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O3 -flto -fuse-ld=lld"`

Now, how do I continue from here, to verify that the bitcode is part of my archive?
I've mostly found solutions for apple (otool), not for ubuntu.
It seems like either llvm-otool, or llvm-objdump and some grepping for the LLVM section should work, but I fail to put the pieces together. Can someone please help me with with
the correct set of commands / flags, startig with my archive?

Edit: Focused my example on the relevant flags.

Comment: `cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/clang++ -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/boost_1_78_0  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O3 -std=c++11 -flto -fuse-ld=lld"` That doesn't tell us anything about the actual build process other that the fact you're using ninja as build tool and clang as C++ compiler. All the other cmake cache entries could simply be overwritten inside the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Furthermore that's even an incorrect use of cmake: According to the documentation the options go before the path to the source dir...

Comment: The C++ standard definetly should be set by the `CMakeLists.txt` file and it should be done using the `cxx_std_11` compile feature, the `CXX_STANDARD` target property or the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable: It's up to the library to determine, if C++11 is required or not.

Comment: @fabian Here is the source code I used, including all the CmakeFiles
https://github.com/evaleev/libint/releases/download/v2.7.0-beta.3/libint-2.7.0-beta.3.tgz

I also adjusted my post. Can you help me with my question now?